# Need help in using Signals with Python Flask

Tags: python, redirect, flask, raspberry-pi, signals

I am new to Python Flask and need some information/basic knowledge on how to use `Signals` with `Flask`.
My understanding so far:

I can create and send own signals. I can use this signal, to make a function call.

My Flask Application looks something like this:

```
@app.route("/")
def start():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/search")
def search():
    rThread = threading.Thread(target=getTags)
    rThread.start()
    return redirect(url_for('search'))
```

The `getTags` in rThread does somemthing outside the application. 
But basically it looks like this:

```
def getTags():
    #do something#
    #now its finished#
```

I want to send a signal when getTags is done and the `Flask` application should get this signal and redirect to index.html.

I am stuck on creating a signal, but I have no clue how to send the signal and how to tell the flask app to redirect to index.html if the signal is sent.

Thanks for any help and advice.

EDIT: For clarification, there are some more pages a user can go to.

```
@app.route("/details")
def det():
    #do stuff
    return render_template('details.html')

@app.route("/admin")
def adm(): 
    if request.method == "GET":
        #do Stuff
        return redirect(url_for('search'))
    else
        #do Stuff
        return render_template("admin.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

It not possible for a web server to trigger an event in client or web browser.
Write a java script function that run for certain interval of time and get data from server and then if the result is required then you redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to wait for a function to do its job you can simply call the function and then respond after it. You used `threading.thread` so you can use `threading.Event` and wait for the event to set by the function:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect
from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep


app = Flask(__name__)
event = Event()


@app.route("/")
def start():
    render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/search")
def search():
    rThread = Thread(target=getTags)
    rThread.start()
    event.wait()
    event.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('start'))


def getTags():
    print("doing some processing things")
    sleep(5)
    print("done")
    event.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event.clear()
    app.run(host="localhost", port="8080", debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I used the thrading.Thread so I dont have to wait for the Thread to wait and proceeed with the main application. 
After the Thread is started, the user can browse on the site and also got to other pages. There are two more routes that the user can go to. So I can't just wait for the Thread to stop, but need a exact signal/event when the thread is done. And if that occurs, catch that event from everywhere in the main application and redirect to the start page.

Comment: You cannot force a webpage to show immediately when your thread ends. If you don't want the user to wait for function. You can just set a flag when the function finished and then on another page show the status of the current state of function. You can also use `push notification` if you want to warn the user.

Comment: From : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/signals/ : "What are signals? Signals help you decouple applications by sending notifications when actions occur elsewhere in the core framework or another Flask extensions. In short, signals allow certain senders to notify subscribers that something happened."